# check if there is space between ordered sublists

Tags: python, list

I would like to check if there are any spaces between nested lists within the given range.
For example

```
ListA = [[5 , 7] , [10, 30], [41, 51]] ##number of sublists are random
Range = [7, 45] 
Results = "in range of [7,45] you have **two** spaces between sublists **[8,9]**,and **[31,40]**" # output
```

so far I've made it to get the sublists in a given range

```
newListA =[]
    for name in m:
    in_range = [i for i in name if any(low <= i <= high for low, high in newListA)]
    newListA_list.append(in_range)
```

Comment: *any spaces between nested lists within the given range.* Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: what I am trying to do is signal is activated at 5~7, 10~30, 41~51, and I am trying to get the periods when the signal is deactivated within the range. which is 8~9,31~40

Comment: Start by describing how you might solve this yourself. Forget about Python syntax for a moment and write some words that explain how you would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the list in adjacent pairs by zipping the list with itself but with an offset of 1, with which you can get the lower bounds and upper bounds of possible spaces, and test if those spaces are within the given range:

```
[
    [low + 1, high - 1]
    for (_, low), (high, _) in zip(ListA, ListA[1:])
    if Range[0] <= low < high <= Range[1]
]
```

With the given sample input, this returns:

```
[[8, 9], [31, 40]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the case of Integers:

If your sub-lists represent ranges, first sort them and unify all the overlaps between them.

Then create a list of the "spaces", for a list:

```
[low1, high1], [low2, high2], [low3, high3]
```

it will be:

```
[0, low1 - 1], [high1 + 1, low2 - 1], [high2 + 1, low3 - 1], [high3 + 1, inf]
```

Then take the "spaces" in the given range.

For the case of floats you can just take open intervals:

```
[0, low1), (high1, low2), (high2, low3), (high3, inf)
```

Comment: Is this really, what OP is asking for? How did you get this from OP's question?

Comment: Yes, he's looking for the algorithm to find the "spaces"